# Jenkins Java: How to get the userid of the user who triggered the build in jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins

Is there a way to find out who started a build in jenkins using java. I understand that below is the approach for figuring out as to who started a build

```
import hudson.model.*  
import jenkins.security.*

def userBuild
for(hudson.model.Cause cause : build.causes) {
    userBuild = cause.getUserName()
}
println "Build Started by: "+userBuild
```

Likewise, can someone please let me know if there is a similar working way to figure out as to who initiated a jenkins build?

Comment: related question : Have you enabled jenkins security?

Comment: @Jayan Yes i have enabled security. The problem here is that i am modifying the jenkins source code so that only the user who triggered the build can cancel the build and no one else can. I am adding that logic in the java and getting the boolean response into the jelly file and then determining whether the cancel button should be enabled or not. unfortunately this is not possible via plugin or groovy, and i think it must be done by tampering with the jenkins source code. Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: what is the difference between "who started a build" and "who initiated a jenkins build"? Please give more information by editing the quesiton

Comment: The first line in the build log i.e. "Build started by user123". This is the one which i want to fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure it out on my own. Added the below changes in buildCaption.jelly so that only the user who started the build will be able to abort the build. Mind that this change only gets reflected in the console-output of a build, but there are other places(such as jenkins landing page and job home page) where the abort button gets displayed and will have to make the changes accordingly

```
<j:forEach var="cause" items="${it.causes}">
    <j:if test="${cause.userName == it.currentlyLoggedInUser}">
      <l:stopButton href="stop" alt="[${%cancel}]"/>
    </j:if>
</j:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ther is a Plugin that injects the informations in Build Variables.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin

> ```
> BUILD_USER – full name of user started build,
> BUILD_USER_FIRST_NAME – first name of user started build,
> BUILD_USER_LAST_NAME – last name of user started build,
> BUILD_USER_ID – id of user started build.
> ```

Maybe this is an option for you.

Comment: I am not looking for a plugin per se, rather i am looking for a way to access the id of the user who triggered the build from the jenkins code itself.